# How fix error for django dumpdata "_django_curs_139705..."

Tags: django, database, psql

Try dumpdata for my projest

```
python3 manage.py dumpdata > dump_12_05_2020.json
```

Get error. How i can fix that?

```
CommandError: Unable to serialize database: cursor "_django_curs_139705045542656_66" does not exist
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error message pop up when trying to datadump.

For what it's worth: in my case, I had some things messed up in my database. Some postgres tables not linked to models in django, and some models in django that had no tables in postgres. When I removed the tables not linked to models and the models not linked to tables, datadump went fine.

Comment: this was my case as well

Comment: same with my case, I had changed my models before dumping data. It's ok if you don't perform the migration, you just need to roll back the changes you u recently made to the model, then dump the data.